# Conditional type declaration

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, std

I'm trying to get a conditional type of file_handle, depending on whether the filename ends with '.gz'. I thought it could be done with std::conditional but the following code does not compile stating:

> error: ‘conditional’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    string filename(argv[1]);
    string file_ext = filename.substr(filename.length()-3, filename.length());
    typedef std::conditional<(file_ext == ".gz"), boost::iostreams::filtering_istream, ifstream>::type file_handle;
    if (file_ext == ".gz"){
        boost::iostreams::file_source myCprdFile (filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        file_handle.push (boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
        file_handle.push (myCprdFile);
    }
    else {
        file_handle.open(filename.c_str());
    }
    std::string itReadLine;

    while (std::getline (bunzip2Filter, itReadLine)) {
      std::cout << itReadLine << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <type_traits>` :)

Comment: You're mixing compile time things with runtime ones (the condition given to `std::conditional` must be known at compile time)

Comment: Templates are compile time feature.

Comment: Then how could I do this at runtime. Looks like I have to write my code twice in an if/else manner... One for gzipped and one for plain text... Am I correct?

Comment: Take a look at [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't really understand boost::variant neither got it to work, I solved it like this, and it's working...

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string filename(argv[1]);
    string file_ext = filename.substr(filename.length()-3, filename.length());
    bool is_gz = false;

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream gzfile_handle;
    ifstream file_handle;

    if (file_ext == ".gz") {
        is_gz = true;
        boost::iostreams::file_source myCprdFile (filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        gzfile_handle.push (boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
        gzfile_handle.push (myCprdFile);
    }
    else {
        file_handle.open(filename.c_str());
    }
    std::string itReadLine;

    while (is_gz ? std::getline (gzfile_handle, itReadLine) : file_handle >> itReadLine) {
      std::cout << itReadLine << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```